# How do I add jar files to imported project from SVN in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Before posting this question, I did NOT see any reference to this topic. I just added the subversive plugin to my Eclipse Juno IDE and my question is after I imported a project from my SVN repository and now have the project setup in eclipse, how do I add JAR files to this project that the code needs to reference?

I do NOT see a configure build path on the project at all.  I am new to subversive and could really use some help.  I tried this in Netbeans 1.7.2 and it gives you the ability to add libraries to the project but I don't see it in Eclipse.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Adding jars to a project build path doesn't have anything to do with SVN and subversive. You add the jar as you would do it without subversive: Project - Properties - Java Buid Path - Libraries - Add JARs/Add External JARs.

Comment: Well, some dev teams check in their Eclipse settings, so junior devs who haven't ever seen any other approach might assume it's all related

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The problem is that there is NO Java Build Path option at all listed.  Since this is coming in from SVN I assumed that is what the issue was and I think it still may be.

Comment: Then you don't have a Java project. How did you create the project? Did you have some pre-existing eclipse project files? Don't you have collegues knowing how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just started at a new job whereby the one .NET developer uses Netbeans per the java developer who left the company.  I wanted to use Eclipse. As stated originally, I imported the project from SVN.  In Netbeans it comes in as a Java project but in Eclipse it just comes in as a TYPE PROJECT.  Hope that helps.   Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Then create a new Java project and make it point to the source files subversive has downloaded.